# NSMutableArray Leak, how to avoid them?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, rx-swift

I spotted a few memory leaks which are connected with `NSMutableArray` in `Core Foundation` and have a big problem with fixing it. My App has been created in Swift 3.0 and it uses `rxSwift`, `CoreData` and `Zip`. As attachment screenshot when this leak appearing. Any suggestions how can I fix it up?

[image]

Comment: how do you do such a screenshot?

Comment: do you handle your `disposable` gracefully? i.e. when a ViewController is being poped / dimiss. You should manual dispose all subscription.

Comment: yes, I do it each time when I use `rxSwift`. On the end each method I call `disposeBag`. Another observables like KVO do not exists in my App.